# Where to place a Jar file when using Tomcat

Tags: java, json, eclipse, tomcat

I am developing an server application using `Tomcat` and `Java EE eclipse`.

Since I need to handle the `Json`, I use the `org.json.jar` and in `eclipse` I add it as an external Jar files, so that my codes can be compiled.

But when I run the server and handle the `Post` request, an error occurs as follows:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.SimpleServlet] in context with path [/MateServer] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
at servlets.SimpleServlet.doPost(SimpleServlet.java:56)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then where should I place the `org.json.jar` file?

Comment: You can put it in your `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` directory or in your project `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: @DarshanPatel I did both... and this error still occurs. It seems that I need to configure the used jar files in some file..

Comment: Try to clean and build your project again then restart your server.Maybe that helps.

Comment: It works... I need to refresh the project in `eclipse`.